# Why did Constantine make a deal with Nergal to stop Zed from becoming the second Mary?

Tags: comics, character-motivation, vertigo-comics, hellblazer

In one of the *Hellblazer* books, the main character discovers that the demon Nergal is trying to kill Constantine's girlfriend Zed,

> because the Resurrection Crusade plans to use her as a second Mary and bring the Second Coming.

When Constantine is wounded, Nergal visits him in the hospital and offers him a deal: Nergal will heal him but Constantine will stop the Crusade.

> Constantine accepted and later had sex with Zed, which taints her and stops the prophecy from fulfilling.

What were his motives here? Was it simply a "get out of hospital fast" card or was he really worried about the effects of prophecy?

EDIT: It seems not many people are interested in Hellblazer... :( Anyway, I can't find this particular fragment in graphic format, but I've found [the synopsis](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Hellblazer_Vol_1_8).

Nergal arguments were (in order):

- Resurrection Crusaders beaten to death Constantine's gay friend: get
  revenge! Constantine refuses.
- Nergal was trying to kill Zed and will probably try it again - hollow laugh as response.
- They have kidnapped and brainwashed your girlfriend - no reaction.
- The child will break the balance between Heaven and Hell - again "not my problem"
- Finally Nergal almost throws a fit saying that if that is Constantine's answer then he will start eating babies out of spite - and then Constantine agrees

I find it bit bizarre that he ignores threats to his friends/loved ones and even to the universe in general showing how big egoistical a-hole Constantine truly is, but simple threat to some babies suddenly changes his mind. Soft spot in the armor of contempt?

Comment: To me it was rather clear that he considered Crusaders' plan dangerous as they might make the child their powerful tool; it doesn't matter what he was telling to Nergal, but what he was thinking later.

Comment: Maybe, but in general Constantine doesn't give a sh@t about anything that doesn't concern him directly

Comment: Well he likes to scr*w over self-rightous a'holes and so he did outwit both antagonists - crusade and demon...